# "Connection to the server was unsuccessful" when attempting to call javascript in a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Unlike other questions of the same title here, the PhoneGap/Android app is working fine and loads views and externally linked javascript files EXCEPT when I'm trying to call a javascript method from te Java side. I'm calling the method like so:

```
public void update(final String data) {
    appView.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            loadUrl("javascript: dispatch('" + data + "')");
        }
    });
}
```

And `update` is called in a non-UI thread.

The thing is that I'm calling the javascript method and the functionality runs, works fine, and does what I expect, but after a few seconds, the app crashes with the error message "Connection to the server was unsuccessful" and the name of the method I'd called. I tried increasing the timeout as suggested in other questions, but it still crashes at the end of the timeout.

Incidentally, I also get a warning about a WebView method being called from a non-UI thread, which is why I added the `post` call, so I'm not sure why that's happening, but it happens right before the timeout error in the log, so maybe it's related?

**Edit**:

I get this error in the log right when the crash happens.

```
03-26 15:21:38.671: W/webview(3159): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-206'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
03-26 15:21:38.671: W/webview(3159):    at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:9468)
03-26 15:21:38.671: W/webview(3159):    at android.webkit.WebView.stopLoading(WebView.java:2253)
03-26 15:21:38.671: W/webview(3159):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap$1$1.run(DroidGap.java:549)
03-26 15:21:38.671: W/webview(3159):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-26 15:21:38.675: E/DroidGap(3159): DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient
```

I was told the `appView.post` would avoid this because it would cause the `loadUrl` call to happen in the UI thread. Apparently this isn't the case?

**EDIT**:

Problem solved. For the record, I changed the `loadURL` line to this:

```
sendJavascript("dispatch('" + data + "')");
```

And it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off calling:

```
this.sendJavaScript("dispatch(('" + data + "')");
```

if your Java class is extending Plugin.

Comment: I'm not extending Plugin, so I don't think this will help.

Comment: You may want to restructure your code a bit to make it a Plugin as it will make the JS to native side communication easier.

Comment: As it turns out, with more googling, other people have recommended sendJavascript as well. I thought I was sending this the right way, but it turns out I wasn't; Eclipse was complaining about how I used it. There seems to be precious little documentation about this method, despite it apparently being the right way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a url timeout..Its a bug in android.

Modify it like this

```
public void update(final String data) {
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("javascript: dispatch('" + data + "')");
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to help. Whatever I change the timeout to there, it just waits that long and then quits with the same error message.

Comment: @jyurek remove the appView.post and directly run it without any thread...I have edited my post

Comment: Both 120000 with the `post` and 60000 without quit right on cue. Not having the `post` and seeing that error is what led me to try to add it in the first place.

Comment: As I said, I tried running it directly, outside the `post`, and it failed. I can't run it outside every thread, though, as this call is being triggered by network activity which is itself in a separate thread.